# Remove Duplicates: Space Complexity for this Code

Tags: java, string, big-o, space-complexity

Given a string without spaces, the task is to remove duplicates from it.

Note: The original order of characters must be kept the same.

*Example:*

```
Input: S = "zvvo"
Output: "zvo"
```

*Explanation:* only keep the first
occurrence

I've written the following code, and I want to know its Space complexity.

```
public class Solution {
    public String removeDups(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++){
            String ch = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
            if (sb.indexOf(ch) == -1)
                sb.append(ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space complexity of your solution is **O(n)** since it requires allocating in memory an instance of `StringBuilder` which would contain up to `n` characters, and transforming it into a `String` of the same length.

These memory costs are fine, but time complexity of your solution can be improved. Presented code runs in **O(n^2)** because method `indexOf()` performs iteration over the characters in your `StringBuilder` instance under the hood, and it's being invoked for every character in the given string.

To reduce the time complexity you can maintain a `HashSet`, and offer each character to the Set, if the character gets rejected it would mean that it was encountered before.

Here's how it might be implemented:

```
public String removeDups(String s) {
    Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (seen.add(ch)) sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Although we are using some additional memory, space complexity remains the same **O(n)** (*because constants are not taken into consideration while evaluating the algorithm's complexity, `2*n` and `3*n` would result in **O(n)***). And time complexity would be linear **O(n)**.